# Field name is not known (Wrong Formula) Crystal Report

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I have problem pertaining to formula but I assure that my work is working because in my crystal report my formula is working but when I run in the application my crystal report getting and it says field name is not known (Wrong Formula)
I have here some illustration [Crystal Report Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbuuC.png)  [this one is the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A70I3.png)

Comment: The message is shown if your database does not contain the mentioned field. Usually when changed the design of the table/view. Or you're not using the same database while designing your report and for your application.

Comment: Error in formula  hospital: 
'if({Command.leave_spentsss} = "1")'
This field name is not known. (That is the only field that i have problem but in my other field is working)

Comment: `Command.leave_spentsss` is not found. Means it does not exist in the database you're connected to. Do you use the same database in your report and for your application? Did you refresh/verify the database connection inside the report?

Comment: Yes @MatSnow is right,please see 'Show SQL Query' in Database MenuItem